# Iframe like button hides count after it is clicked

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I've added iframe like button into the page http://www.electric-yoga.com/contact.html.
When I click on this button it shows +1 count, but in 1 second this count disappears.
Linter shows no errors - http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electric-yoga.com%2Fcontact.html.
Any advice where I can look for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am running into this same issue using the HTML5 version of the like button.  The really weird thing is that the issue doesn't happen on all of the pages that we have a like button on.  I found a bug on the [Facebook Developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335677499790580?browse=search_4f0de4af319d57986995304) and have submitted a repro.  I suggest you do the same to give it some more visibility.  You're not alone.